# How to fix deserialization error when posting an array of objects

Tags: c#, json, api

"Message": "The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState": {
        "notification": [

"Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'iBasement.Models.Notification' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.\r\nPath '', line 1, position 1."

trying to call a post with an array like this:

```
POST /api/Notifications/UpdateMac HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:56005
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.17.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 4ac88367-af2c-48e8-99a0-b89fba2ea76a,c1f78db8-e040-4675-9103-5c9c41273c24
Host: localhost:56005
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 507
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache

[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "MacAddress": "f8:f0:05:ed:1d:28",
        "Destination": "janedoe@gmail.com",
        "SendAlertTypes": "0,1,4,5,6"
    },
    {
        "Id": 6,
        "MacAddress": "f8:f0:05:ed:1d:28",
        "Destination": "johndoe@hotmail.com",
        "SendAlertTypes": "0,1,2,3,4,5,6"
    },
    {
        "Id": 99,
        "MacAddress": "f8:f0:05:ed:1d:28",
        "Destination": "4012221234@vtext.com",
        "SendAlertTypes": "0,1,2,3,4,5,6"
    }
]

[Route("~/UpdateMac")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostNotifications([FromBody]List<Notification> notifications)
{
    //do list operations..
}

public class Notification

{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MacAddress { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    //"0,1,2,3,6" <-- 4, 5, & 7+ would be omitted
    public string SendAlertTypes { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: Any chance you're actually sending `{"notification": [....]}` instead of the actual `[..]` ?

Comment: @OrelEraki no, that is exactly how the body is currently sent in my PostMan message

Comment: Mind showing us a picture of the raw request being sent ? (body and headers)

Comment: What's the structure in iBasement.Models.Notification.

Comment: @OrelEraki Added info

Comment: @Peter-Yu Added class

Comment: @JamesHDev, you're doing many mistakes when posting question. 1. Please supply all relevant information: Request, Server ControllerAction, Exception (formatted so we can read it), and classes which relevant on the Deserialized object.

Comment: @OrelEraki It was supposed to be an abstract, general question. Given an array in the body of a post (as shown above), how can I accept and deserialize it. The request is there, the controllerAction is there, the class is there, and the exception is there and appears to be a commonly searched error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have couple of issues, but none of them is producing me the exception you are getting.

1. Duplicate of **Host** header, this should be removed.
2. Routing
   Code sample is using `[Route("~/UpdateMac")]`, which means "Ignore all route prefix attributes" thus, you can only call this action only without any other path before it.
   Will not work: `POST /api/Notifications/UpdateMac HTTP/1.1`
   Will work: `POST /UpdateMac HTTP/1.1`

If you still want to use the full `/api/Notifications/UpdateMac` routing, here are just couple of ways of doing it

1. Change `[Route("~/UpdateMac")]` to `[Route("api/Notifications/UpdateMac")]`.
2. Decorate the controller with `[RoutePrefix("api/Notifications")]` and change the action to `[Route("UpdateMac")]` (without tilde).

In none of those experiments i encounter with deserialization issue, which probably means, the client somehow produce different request, try maybe using **Fiddler** or **curl** until finding the mismatch in **PostMan**.

Comment: thank you for sticking with me here. That was the main issue. Without the proper Route decoration it was attempting to do the standard Post. I am still trying to figure out how to get the array from the body into a list. Can I ask you in another comment or update the question above or should I just open a new thread entirely?

Comment: It's confusing, because You asked X, i answer on Y, so if you will open a new question on X it may regarded as duplication. It will be better the continue solving the exception here. But! i used your exact scenario locally and it worked well, thus i'll recommend you to try Fiddler or curl before that. (And yes i know PostMan is great for that)